# Sending notification using notificationhub in Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-notificationhub

I'm using azure function(set to trigger on manual input) to send notification messages to mobile devices. My code is complied without any problem and it runs just fine. However, I'm not getting any messages from my device. I checked values of "Notification Hubs namespace connection", "Notification Hub name" and "Tag expression" and they all have correct values. Am I missing something here?

This is my code :

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs;

public static void Run(string input, out string notification, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# manually triggered function called with input: {input}");
    notification = "{\"message\":\"Hello from C#. Processed a queue item!\"}";
}
```

EDIT : I get all the messages send by using "Test Send" feature of notification hub. I also get all the message send to my webapp interacting with notification hub. I just want to get rid of that webapp and replace it with Azure function.

EDIT : My code is based on this tutorial -

[Accessing notification hub from Azure function](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-bindings-notification-hubs/)

Comment: To send push notifications via azure functions, you need to configure NotificaitonHub and clients need to register with the hub: 1. Configure Notification Hub: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/
2. Register template from client either via Mobile Apps : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/#register-xplat or using NotificationHub SDK : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-send-localized-breaki

Comment: Yup I've done all of those. I get messages send with "Test Send" from notificationhub. And I also have backend (written in asp.net) interacting with notificationhub. I can get messages from that too. I just want to get rid of that backend and replace it with azure function. Unfortunately, azure function is not working and I'm scratching my head trying to figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: I just sent an email. Thanks!